# XAMPP Apache Web Server not starting

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I have xampp 7.3.0 and the apache web server and MySQL database are not starting.

I'm getting the error code: Syntax error on line 523 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

this is the line at 523: Include "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf/httpd.conf"

[Img of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqcGl.png) 
[Img of line 523](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I42cO.png)

So I'm not sure what to change to fix the syntax.

Comment: So what is the content of that line in the condiguration? Or is this meant to be a guessing game?

Comment: @arkascha Hi! If you finished reading the question you would have seen that I included what line 523 says: "this is the line at 523: Include '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'" By no means a guessing game, just a question. I've added an image for visual communication.

Comment: Looks like a cyclic inclusion, doesn't it?

Comment: @arkascha yeah I'm not sure why this is happening because I didn't edit these lines.

Comment: So what does that included file include?